# React Native : Why is "navigation" not being passed to my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been working on this problem for two days now and nothing on the web seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

I am attempting to implement a StackNavigator into my React Native app, but for some reason "navigation" is not being passed as a prop to the involved components. Therefore when I call `this.props.navigation.navigator` by pressing Button, I get the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)`.

I have logged the props several times and the props object is empty, so the issue is not a deconstruction-of-the-props-object issue like others who get this error have had, but the fact that the navigation prop is not there in the first place.

I've tried placing the navigator code in its own file and in the App.js file thinking that it was somehow called after the components are rendered, and therefore not getting a chance to pass the navigation prop in, but that didn't work either.  I've also looked to see if it is part of the props in the componentDidMount event.  Still not.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'


import { getDecks } from '../utils/api'
import NewDeckView from './NewDeckView'
import DeckListItem from './DeckListItem'






export default class DeckListView extends Component {

        constructor(props){


            super(props)

            this.state = {

                decks: []
            }


        }


        componentDidMount(){

            console.log('props now test',this.props)
            getDecks()
            .then( result => {

                const parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
                const deckNames = Object.keys(parsedResult);
                const deckObjects  = [];
                deckNames.forEach( deckName => {
                    parsedResult[deckName].key = parsedResult[deckName].title    
                    deckObjects.push(parsedResult[deckName])
                })

                this.setState({
                    decks:deckObjects
                })

            } )
        }





        render(){

            return (



                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Text style={styles.header}>Decks</Text>
                        <FlatList data={this.state.decks} renderItem={({item})=><DeckListItem title={item.title} noOfCards={item.questions?item.questions.length:0}/>} />
                        <Button styles={styles.button} title="New Deck" onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('NewDeckView')}}/>
                    </View>

            )
        }       
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({


    header:{
        fontSize:30,
        margin:20,

    },

    container:{

        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'flex-start',
        alignItems:'center'
    },

    button:{

        width:50
    }
})


const Stack = StackNavigator({

        DeckListView : {
            screen: DeckListView,

        },

        NewDeckView: {
            screen:NewDeckView,

        }


    })
```

Comment: you are mounting the navigator right? you cant juts mount the list view class, you have mount the stack navigator for the navigation prop to work

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "mount"?  My call to StackNavigator is at the bottom by the way..

Comment: means u should render Stack as the root so it displays the first screen

Comment: Yea, I've tried rendering it at App.js before the root component definition and it didnt work.

Comment: I think you aren't calling `Stack` from anywhere like this: `<Stack />` because you haven't exported it. Can you provide the code for the entry point of the app or any code repo?, so that we can give a concrete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Vicky and Shubhnik Singh mentioned, you need to render the imported navigation stack in App.js like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Stack } from './navigator/navigator'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return <Stack/>
  }
}
```

The navigator should look something like this and the first key in the object passed to StackNavigator will be rendered by default.  In this case, it will be DeckListView.

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import DeckListView from '../components/DeckListView'
import NewDeckView from '../components/NewDeckView'



export const Stack = StackNavigator({

    DeckListView : {
        screen: DeckListView,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'Home',
},
    },


    NewDeckView: {
        screen:NewDeckView,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'New Deck',
},
    },




})
```

Thanks guys for the support! Somehow this wasn't clear for me in the documentation.